# Load another widget on google app engine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I m developing a google app engine java project. It 's my first project of this kind so I will something stupid. I first add one widget or more with get().add(widget) on myproject.java file in the client folder and all going great.

But I wondering if I can load a widget and run it separately (maybe a widget for inserting a photo) and see only this widget on the screen after a listener. With simple words I want to have 5 buttons on my main widget and every button to load it's own widget. Can I do that in java?

Comment: Are you sure that you're working with Google App Engine? because googel appenginge is server side techology, but you're asking about client side things. https://developers.google.com/appengine/?hl=en

Comment: It is a little hard to understand what you exactly want so you should probably post the code/link of the stuff that you did.